# Joining different tables based on column value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called `notifications`:

```
CREATE TABLE `notifications` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `parent_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent_type` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `etc` NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=25 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Each `notification` is related to a different table, the value of `parent_type` field specifies the name of the table that I want to `* join` the table with. All target tables have several similar columns:

```
CREATE TABLE `tablename` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `is_visible` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,      
  `etc` NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Currently I'm using this query for selecting notifcations that their related row in the target table exists and their `is_visible` field is `1`:

```
SELECT n.id, 
FROM notifications n 
LEFT JOIN books b ON n.parent_id = b.id AND n.parent_type = 'book' AND b.is_visible = 1
LEFT JOIN interviews i ON n.parent_id = i.id AND n.parent_type = 'interview' AND i.is_visible = 1
LEFT JOIN other tables...
WHERE n.user_id = 1
GROUP BY n.id
```

But since it is a `LEFT JOIN` it returns the notification if it matches any table or not, how can I rewrite it so it doesn't return notifications that don't match with any row in the target table? I have also tried the `CASE` statement unsuccessfully.

Comment: did you tried just without `LEFT ` and using `JOIN` Only?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure the syntax is right and I have no chance to test it right now, but the idea should be clear.

```
SELECT DISTINCT n.id 
FROM notifications n 
JOIN (
     (SELECT b.id, 'book' AS type FROM books b WHERE b.is_visible = 1)
  UNION
     (SELECT i.id, 'interview' AS type FROM interviews i WHERE i.is_visible = 1)
) ids ON n.parent_id = ids.id AND n.parent_type = ids.type
WHERE n.user_id = 1
```

Comment: Using `JOIN` and `UNION` does the trick. Thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks! It was help to me!

Comment: Note: This syntax is for MySQL only. Does NOT work for SQLite.