# Unable to make join query in mysql or my table structure is wrong

Tags: php, mysql

HI
I Have three tables on which i want to make join

**USER TABLE**
 [image] 
  **ROLE TABLE**
 [image] 
**OWNER TABLE** 
 [image] 
**TENANT TABLE** 
 [image]

I want to get username, firstName, LastName

process:- 
**strong text**
1. on the basis of **roleID** we can join **ROLE TABLE** & get **reference table**  
2. NOW MY QUESTION START 
3. if reference table 
 which we get from step 1
 is **owner**,then **join with owner table** table OR 
  if reference table is **tenant**, then **join with tenant table** table  
4. FINALLY I WANT FOLLOWING DATA 
 id
 username
 firstName
 lastName

Comment: Thanks Gordon Linoff

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff
is it sufficient or i should provide some more details

Comment: Does this answer point you in the right direction : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18555603/joining-different-tables-based-on-column-value

Comment: @ PaulF 
Thanks  PaulF , i already view that question but unable to find something that can help me

Comment: @AnkitArjaria the problem is in mysql you can not have conditional join however you can always do conditional select, so you need to predefine the joining clause ( not dynamically) Here is a fiddle http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b3574/1 which could help you.

Comment: @Abhik Chakraborty, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this based on the answer I directed you to :

```
select tt.id, username, fn, ln
from usertb ut
join roletb rt on ut.roleid=rt.id
join 
(
select id ID, 'owner' tbname, firstname FN, lastname LN from ownertb
UNION
select id ID, 'tenant' tbname, firstname FN, lastname LN from tenanttb
) tt ON tt.id=ut.refid AND rt.referenceTable=tt.tbname
```