# Joining two tables based on column value

Tags: mysql, sql, join, case

I need to join different tables if a condition meets on the first join,  so, if a column of the first join has a value 1 then do a join with one table, but if the value has 2 then do the join with another table, something like this but MySQL give an error

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3,...,col8
FROM table1 AS tb1
INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON tb1.id = tb2.id
INNER JOIN table3 AS t3 ON tb2.id = tb3.id
CASE
    WHEN tb2.col2 = 1   THEN INNER JOIN table4 ON id = col1
    WHEN tb2.col2 = 2   THEN INNER JOIN table5 ON id = col3
    WHEN tb2.col2 = 3   THEN INNER JOIN table6 ON id = col5
END    
WHERE tb1.id = 13;
```

Comment: check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18555603/joining-different-tables-based-on-column-value

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `case` *expression* returns a value, and can't be used for conditional execution of code. Do `LEFT JOIN`s instead.

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3,...,col8
FROM table1 AS tb1
INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON tb1.id = tb2.id
INNER JOIN table3 AS t3 ON tb2.id = tb3.id
LEFT JOIN table4 ON id = col1 and tb2.col2 = 1
LEFT JOIN table5 ON id = col3 and tb2.col2 = 2
LEFT JOIN table6 ON id = col5 and tb2.col2 = 3
WHERE tb1.id = 13;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with LEFT joins and filter in the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3,...,col8
FROM table1 AS tb1
INNER JOIN table2 AS tb2 ON tb1.id = tb2.id
INNER JOIN table3 AS tb3 ON tb2.id = tb3.id
LEFT JOIN table4 ON id = col1 AND tb2.col2 = 1
LEFT JOIN table5 ON id = col3 AND tb2.col2 = 2
LEFT JOIN table6 ON id = col5 AND tb2.col2 = 3
WHERE tb1.id = 13 AND tb2.col2 IN (1, 2, 3);
```

Note that all columns should be qualified with the respective table name/alias.